# Jquery - Limit insertion of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a repeater field within my table.

Basically I want the following behavior:

1. If no "*Test Product2*" has been added to the table, the user cannot add another field below.
2. If a "*Test Product2*" has been added to the table, the user is allowed to add a field below and can add another "Test Product2" next to the new blue button.

The below an example of the second case for the behaviour.

[image]

```js
$(".btn.btn-dark.btn-sm.product2").on("click", this.clickDispatcherTable.bind(this))
//$(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm").on("click", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this));
$("#miningTable").on("click", ".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.product2", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this));

function clickDispatcherTable(e) {
  let plusButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-dark.btn-sm")

  if (plusButton.hasClass("product2")) {
    let plusButtonParent = plusButton[0].parentElement.parentElement;
    plusButtonParent.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product2
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
            `)
  }
}

function ourClickDispatcher(e) {

  let targetButton = $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.product2")

  let targetButtonParent = targetButton[0].parentElement

  targetButtonParent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `
                <td>
                    <img src="" alt="" height="42" width="42">
                    <a href="">
                        Test Product2
                    </a>
                </td>    
            `)

  targetButton.attr('class', 'btn btn-danger btn-sm product2'); // change button class to red

  targetButton.text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace("Add", "Edit");
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="miningTable" style="float: left;" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product2
                                        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm product2">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product3" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product3">
                                            Add Product3
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product 4</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product4" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product4">
                                            Add Product4
                                     
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see in the above example a user can add multiple fields as he want. There is currently no restriction.

Any suggestions how to restrict the user for adding a field if a condition is not satisfied?

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: _if no_ ? what is the condition ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Basically the user has to add a "Test Product2" first before he can add a button. So if no, would be that the user cannot add a button.

Comment: Check the last child's `TestPproduct2`

Comment: @Saeed.At I kindly ask you for an example!

Comment: your question is quite confusing , don't know about which condition you are talking about

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Thx for your reply! Simply said, I only want to a blue button below if the text `"Test Product2"` is already added on the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, think this is your answer

```
function clickDispatcherTable(e) {
  let plusButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-dark.btn-sm")
  let sw = true;
  $( "tbody tr" ).each(function(index, row) {
    if(row.children.length != 3) {
      sw = false;
    }
  });

  if (sw) {
    $('tbody tr:last').after(`
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" data-exists="product2" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm product2">
                                            Add Product2
                                        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>`)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your solution! However, the `tr:last-child td` does not work as I do not only have one row in my example, but a whole table with lot`s of rows.

Comment: You have more than one button which adds new row to your table?@mrquad

Comment: Ok, It is your problem : You have a table with some rows which they do not have `TestPproduct2`. You want the user be able to add new row if he fill all previous rows??@mrquad

Comment: Your solution is totally right. This is exactly the behavior that I would like to have! I am looking for a more generalized approach, that could be fit in a larger table with many different rows(see my example above!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169347/discussion-between-saeed-at-and-mrquad).